# Symfony- Implement identity confirmation after each request

Tags: php, security, symfony, session

I'm implementing a counter measure for sessions hijacking on Symfony. Basically check if user hasn't change an IP and/or their user agent during the session. Basic stuff.

The thing is that I don't know where exactly should I put this code in order to run it after each request. Basically to change is something changed after the last request.

My code for now looks like that

```
static protected function preventHijacking(Session $session)
{
    $ipAddress = $session->get('IPaddress');
    $userAgent = $session->get('userAgent');

    $remoteAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $httpUserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if(!isset($ipAddress) || !isset($userAgent)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($ipAddress != $remoteAddress) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($userAgent != $httpUserAgent) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My second question is :

- Do you guys have a better implementation for this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question: it depends on when you're creating the session. If sessions are only used for logged in users or if that's the only use case that you want to protect then putting this logic into an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` would work best. This involves extending `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and adding in the above logic; then in your `security.yml` adding the entry under the `success_handler` parameter ([see the reference documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)) for this.

If you want to protect all sessions, then extending your session handler and putting this code in its initialisation or save methods would probably be the best - I'm not familiar with the Redis session handler class so couldn't advised more than this. Once you've extended the session handler, just configure Symfony to use your session handler with its added logic.

As for your second question: checking IP address like this has its own foibles for connections that don't stay on the same IP address between requests e.g. corporations that load balance their internet connections and don't thread them for web requests. Realistically if you've turned off obtaining the session ID from URLs which is the main vector for session hijacking, then really this is, in my opinion, overkill. I guess it depends on what you're securing and the impact this would have on it. Far better would be to have SSL throughout, HSTS enabled and secure cookies on and forget about trying to mitigate at this level.

Comment: I'll start by answering about the second part. Checking the IP address is not that practical, for now I'm not relying fully on it to kick out the user, I'm just raising a flag somewhere as I will be thinking more about this in the future.

About the first suggestion, I'll be playing with those more in depth this weekend and get back to you. Thx !